# Windows 2000 Server on VMware Workstation is not booting

Tags: vmware-workstation, windows-2000, vmdk

I am trying to open a Windows 2000 server using VMware Workstation.
it seems I am not having all the relevant files of the environment. I guess the server was partitioned with 3 parts. I am not having the vmdk for the 3rd part. there are some REDO files. Is there anyway i can create the vmdk for the 3rd part?

So now it gives error.
Now I don't have the physical environment. So please help and guide is it possible to recover or make this work.

[image]

the log file had following:

```
2016-06-24T14:04:07.812+05:30| vmx| I120: hread 792 5924VMXAIOMGR: Using: simple=Generic unbuf=Compl
2016-06-24T14:04:07.822+05:30| vmx| I120: WORKER: Creating new group with numThreads=1 (20)
2016-06-24T14:04:07.822+05:30| vmx| I120: SNAPSHOT: SnapshotConfigInfoReadEx: Snapshot failed due to version error: 7
2016-06-24T14:04:07.822+05:30| vmx| I120: SNAPSHOT: SnapshotConfigInfoReadEx failed for file 'OS 2000 Server.vmx.sav': Snapshots are not allowed on this virtual machine (9)
2016-06-24T14:04:07.822+05:30| vmx| I120: SNAPSHOT: Snapshot_ListRollingTiers failed: Snapshots are not allowed on this virtual machine (9)
2016-06-24T14:04:07.822+05:30| vmx| I120: SnapshotVMX_RollingPowerOn: failed to initialize rolling snapshots Snapshots are not allowed on this virtual machine (9)
2016-06-24T14:04:07.842+05:30| vmx| I120: DISK: OPEN scsi0:0 'C:\pr\BAAN\LN6.1FP3\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk' undoable R[.\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836]
2016-06-24T14:04:07.902+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-DSCPTR: Opened [0]: "Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk-s001.REDO_a03836" (0xa)
2016-06-24T14:04:07.942+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-DSCPTR: Opened [1]: "Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk-s002.REDO_a03836" (0xa)
2016-06-24T14:04:08.002+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-DSCPTR: Opened [2]: "Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk-s003.REDO_a03836" (0xa)
2016-06-24T14:04:08.002+05:30| vmx| I120: AIOWIN32C: Failed to open '.\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk-s004.REDO_a03836' : Could not find the file (3).
2016-06-24T14:04:08.002+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-SPARSE: Opening unbuffered failed; trying Simple.
2016-06-24T14:04:08.002+05:30| vmx| I120: AIOGNRC: Failed to open '.\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk-s004.REDO_a03836' : Could not find the file (600000003) (0x3).
2016-06-24T14:04:08.002+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-SPARSE: ".\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk-s004.REDO_a03836" : failed to open (25): AIOMgr_Open failed
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-LINK  : ".\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836" : failed to open (The system cannot find the file specified).  
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-CHAIN : ".\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836" : failed to open (The system cannot find the file specified).
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: DISKLIB-LIB   : Failed to open '.\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836' with flags 0xa The system cannot find the file specified (25).
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: DISK: Failed to open disk '.\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836' : The system cannot find the file specified (25) 5456.
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: Msg_Post: Error
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: [msg.disk.fileNotFound] VMware Player cannot find the virtual disk ".\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836". Verify the path is valid and try again.
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: [msg.disk.noBackEnd2] Cannot open either the disk 'C:\pr\BAAN\LN6.1FP3\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk' or the redo log '.\Windows 2000 Server (2).vmdk.REDO_a03836'.
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: [msg.disk.configureDiskError] Reason: The system cannot find the file specified.
2016-06-24T14:04:08.132+05:30| vmx| I120: ----------------------------------------
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: Module DiskEarly power on failed.
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: VMX_PowerOn: ModuleTable_PowerOn = 0
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: SNAPSHOT: SnapshotConfigInfoReadEx: Snapshot failed due to version error: 7
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: SNAPSHOT: SnapshotConfigInfoReadEx failed for file 'C:\pr\BAAN\LN6.1FP3\OS 2000 Server.vmx.sav': Snapshots are not allowed on this virtual machine (9)
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: SNAPSHOT: Snapshot_TimeStampTiers failed: Snapshots are not allowed on this virtual machine (9)
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: SnapshotVMX_RollingPowerOff: Failed to timestamp rolling tiers at power off: Snapshots are not allowed on this virtual machine (9)
2016-06-24T14:04:28.093+05:30| vmx| I120: AIOWIN32C: asyncOps=0 syncOps=48 bufSize=0Kb fixedOps=0 sgOps=24 sgOn=1
2016-06-24T14:04:28.103+05:30| aioCompletion| I120: AIO thread processed 0 completions
2016-06-24T14:04:28.103+05:30| vmx| I120: AIOWIN32: asyncOps=0 syncOps=0 bufSize=0Kb delayed=0 fixed=0 sgOp=0 sgOn=1
2016-06-24T14:04:28.183+05:30| vmx| I120: WORKER: asyncOps=0 maxActiveOps=0 maxPending=0 maxCompleted=0
2016-06-24T14:04:28.183+05:30| WinNotifyThread| I120: WinNotify thread exiting
2016-06-24T14:04:28.193+05:30| vmx| I120: Vix: [6036 mainDispatch.c:4067]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=1, newAppState=1873, success=1 additionalError=0
2016-06-24T14:04:28.193+05:30| vmx| I120: Vix: [6036 mainDispatch.c:4067]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=0, newAppState=1870, success=1 additionalError=0
2016-06-24T14:04:28.193+05:30| vmx| I120: Transitioned vmx/execState/val to poweredOff
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: Vix: [6036 mainDispatch.c:4067]: VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished: statevar=0, newAppState=1870, success=0 additionalError=0
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: Vix: [6036 mainDispatch.c:4106]: Error VIX_E_FAIL in VMAutomation_ReportPowerOpFinished(): Unknown error
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: VMX idle exit
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: VMIOP: Exit
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: Vix: [6036 mainDispatch.c:869]: VMAutomation_LateShutdown()
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: Vix: [6036 mainDispatch.c:819]: VMAutomationCloseListenerSocket. Closing listener socket.
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: Flushing VMX VMDB connections
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: VmdbDbRemoveCnx: Removing Cnx from Db for '/db/connection/#1/'
2016-06-24T14:04:28.203+05:30| vmx| I120: VmdbCnxDisconnect: Disconnect: closed pipe for pub cnx '/db/connection/#1/' (0)
2016-06-24T14:04:28.213+05:30| vmx| I120: VMX exit (0).
2016-06-24T14:04:28.213+05:30| vmx| I120: AIOMGR-S : stat o=1 r=3 w=0 i=0 br=49152 bw=0
2016-06-24T14:04:28.213+05:30| vmx| I120: FileTrack_Exit: done
```

Answer (score 2):

Redo files are set for differential disk type stuff (e.g. you have a "locked" source VMDK disk and one or more virtual machines that use that as a source and write their 'changes' to the Redo file rather than to the vmdk.

The error you're seeing there suggests that the virtual machine's bios is set to boot from the network only, and isn't finding a source to boot from on the network.

So...

- Check the virtual drives are correctly attatched in the VM settings.
- Check the BIOS on the virtual guest can see the hard drive, and that it is set to boot from it.

If you've actually lost the VMDK files for any virtual machine then you're hosed.